# SELECT value and INSERT it INTO a new row?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sql-insert

I want to select `BlockHash` value from the last row in the table `pow` and insert it into `BlockLastHash` in the new row, How can I do that?

I tried this code:

```
 connection.query("SELECT `BlockHash` FROM `pow` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", (err, res) => {
     if(err) throw err;
        
     connection.query("INSERT INTO `pow` (`BlockData`, `BlockHash`, `BlockLastHash`, `dataid`) VALUES ('"+blockdata+"', '"+hash+"', '"+res+"' , '"+id+"') ", (err, res2) => {
         if(err) throw err;
         console.log("1 Block inserted");  
     });
 });
```

The output in `BlockLastHash` is `[object Object]`

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results object supports multiple rows returned and multiple fields for each row; you need to tell it what you want to get from the result.  Try:

```
res[0].BlockHash
```

In addition to err and res, a fields object is also available that describes what fields are returned.